# How to subdividing curves

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, subdivision-surface

I am trying to model apple magic mouse in Blender so in order to create those curves I used "Bezier curve", so in the end when I finished modeling and convert it to mesh I got this:
[image]

[image]

But when I try to use subdivide modifier it I get:
[image]

Is there some way to fix this, or this is just how subdivide works with curves?

Comment: If editing the curves before they are converted to mesh is no longer an option, e.g. you lost the curve data, then I suggest removing all mentions of curves from the question - after all there no longer are any curves there. What you're doing is subdividing a mesh. I think you need to watch some beginner Blender tutorials to see the proper workflow with subdivision surface modifier. The "topology" (not just the visual shape of your mesh, but how it is defined with edges) greatly affects the result of modifiers (be it bevel, deform, subdivision surface and more).

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Tnx for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not seeing a curve but a mesh. To have a good result with your *Subdivision Surface* modifier you need to have a better topology, i.e avoid ngons and create quads instead, here are the edge loops that you could keep (use the *Knife* tool for example), remove all the other ones (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve the edges):

[image]